# How to reduce the size of watermark using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

I have 2 images:

1. a PNG which is a log
2. thumbnail which is JPG

   ```
   ffmpeg -i thumb-168pa-usrao.jpg -i evercam-logo-white.png  -filter_complex  'overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h)' test.jpg
   ```

how we can reduce the size of watermark? to half of its size?

Comment: How large is the JPEG?

Comment: It can be upto 4MB

Comment: Resolution, not file size.

Comment: Not fixed it can varry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i thumb-168pa-usrao.jpg -i evercam-logo-white.png -filter_complex '[1]scale=iw/2:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-10:y=main_h-overlay_h-10' test.jpg
```

This will "reduce the size of watermark to half of its size".

Comment: Can you tell how we can move watermark little to left?

Comment: @JunaidFarooq See updated answer. Also see [How to add watermark to video with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/1109017)

Comment: Hey, i want to post another question if you can help? I have a video and I want to put the watermark on that as well but I know how to add it after creating mp4, is there anyway to just add watermark while making mp4 vidoe?